# Does this qualify as recursion?

Tags: java

I am aware that a function calling itself is recursive. But, is an object creating objects of it's own type recursive? Additionally, I have no intention of using this code as it will quite obviously cause problems, I'm only interested in whether or not it qualifies as recursion.

```
class Cell 
{
    Cell()
    {
        Cell c = new Cell();
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't even compile in C++. :)

Comment: It qualifies as a stack overflow.

Comment: @Kayaman oh boy oh boy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8mYLi3PGOc

Comment: @selbie You just need to imagune that there is another constructor `Cell(Cell*)` in the omitted code :)

Comment: if you had a suitable base clause, then yes.

Comment: Althought your question was _is an object creating objects of it's own type recursive?_ ppl are now talking about validity of your code :) By definition recursion is a method where the solution to a problem depends on solutions to smaller instances of the same problem.. imho in your code there is no problem and solution

Comment: Also in a recursive function, you should have an escape condition to eventually stop the recursion.

Comment: @Kayaman - oh noes! maybe I won't ship this code now.

Comment: @selbie very interesting... even if adding an escape hatch?

Comment: I wonder what will code fail with when you run it..? stackoverflow may be?

Comment: @B001 come on mate, in plain English - recursion is a function calling itself, this code is recursive.

Comment: @DavidWilson you should add some unit tests, and comments, and documentation

Comment: _come on mate, in plain English - recursion is a function calling itself_ Are we talking about human languages or technical definitons?`

Comment: I believe @Joe is employing sarcasm to highlight how many people, as is often the case on Stack Overflow, are opting to comment on anything other than the question that was asked. You, yourself even pointed out, how people were talking about code validity rather than answering the question then went on to address 'problems and solutions' which absolutely not what was asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed it does. The `Cell` constructor will be called by itself, assuming that some calling code sets off the construction of a `Cell` instance.

Unless you *block* the recursion somehow (perhaps with a maximum instance limit), your program will eventually crash.

Comment: If compiler eliminates recursion and actual memory of Cell is not touched, you might have to wait for address space exhaustion.